# Error 424 Object required 3

Tags: vba, excel

Can someone help me figure out why I'm getting this error?  Here is my code and it says the error starts on line 3.

```
Sub Select_Button()
    Msg = ""
    For i = 0 To ListBox7.ListCount - 1
        If ListBox7.Selected(i) Then
            Msg = Msg & ListBox7.List(i) & vbNewLine
        End If
    Next i
    MsgBox "You Selected: " & vbNewLine & Msg
    Unload UserForm
End Sub
```

Comment: add `Option Explicit`, it will tell you which part you haven't defined yet.

Answer (score 3):

A `UserForm` is a *class*, not an *object*. `Unload` is for unloading an *object*.

The error stems from this line:

```
Unload UserForm
```

If your form is named `UserForm1`, then it should read:

```
Unload UserForm1
```

**HOWEVER** this goes against best practices and will eventually bite you in the rear end.

Forms have a *default, global instance*, so when you do this:

```
UserForm1.Show vbModal
```

You're working with the *default instance*, not a new object. If you do `Unload UserForm1` you're unloading that *default instance*, which means if you instead do the right thing and use an *object* like this:

```
With New UserForm1
    .Show vbModal
    '...
End With
```

Then unloading the *default instance* will definitely not do what you thought it would do.

That's why you want to be using the `Me` keyword whenever you mean to refer to the *current instance* of an object. So to unload the *current instance* of a `UserForm1` object, you need to do this:

```
Unload Me
```

**Consider** calling `Me.Hide` instead of *unloading* the object, and implementing your logic *outside* the form's code-behind. Future you will be thankful.